# Debugging a failure to access libleveldb with C# on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, pinvoke, visual-studio-debugging, leveldb

A C# project I'm interested in uses `leveldb` via a PInvoke ['wrapper'](https://github.com/neo-project/neo/blob/master/neo/IO/Data/LevelDB/Native.cs#L127) that works fine on both Windows and Linux but throws the following error on OSX.

> src/tcmalloc.cc:331] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7f83cb954a00

A minimal example to reproduce the error with is

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace leveldb_test2
{
    internal static class Native {
        [DllImport("libleveldb", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr leveldb_options_create();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("before");
            IntPtr handle = Native.leveldb_options_create();
            Console.WriteLine("after");
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried**

- Manually building leveldb

  Leveldb was initially installed via homebrew. Not knowing if they do anything magical, I also did a manual build which gave me the same error.
- Verifying the method signature

  The method signature used with DllImport seems ok, as it's identical to what's used in a wrapper project I found: [leveldb-sharp](https://github.com/meebey/leveldb-sharp/blob/master/Native.cs#L391) (fwiw; I tried using that project, same error)

  Note that original export from `leveldb` is
  `extern leveldb_options_t* leveldb_options_create();`

  I also created my own dll with the same signature and that worked fine. This also confirmed for me that I can correctly enforce which exact library file is being loaded to avoid it using some broken version somewhere else on my system.
- Verifying library exports

  I dumped the exports using `nm` to make sure no name mangling is going on, seems fine.
  I can also access the library successfully with `ctypes` in Python.
- Try older versions of leveldb

  I tried all older versions up to 1.15 from September 2014. All give the same error.

**What's next**

Ideally, I'd like to be able to debug the native side. However, unlike with Visual Studio on Windows, the OSX Visual Studio Community Edition doesn't have the "Enable native code debugging" option described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode). So my question is

*How would I go about debugging the native side while initiated from C#?*

I believe the latter part of this question is important, because as said before it works fine when initiated from Python. Any tips/hints/help are much appreciated!

PS: a bonus would be the solution to getting the wrapper to work.

Comment: You should be able to use gdb for native debugging on macOS but I have no personal experience doing this from mono. Maybe `mcs --aot=full` spits out a fully native binary?

Comment: did you find a solution ? I'm having exactly the same problem (with a wrapper of leveldb as well)

Comment: @Olivier unfortunately not. I ended up creating a proxy that forwards all `leveldb` calls to `rocksdb` (95+% could be forwarded 1on1).

Comment: This is not necessarily the answer to "how to debug", but it's the solution for why I asked the question in the first place. Set `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/lib/libtcmalloc.dylib` prior to running and it should be good. You might get a `Library Validation` warning (thanks Apple) but other than that it worked for me.